# In Excel, how to return a string appearing after a string from a list (no delimiters)

Tags: arrays, excel, match, vlookup

I have a list of categories followed by string (no spaces or characters in between). I have the categories in a separate column and need to get the corresponding remaining string in the next column.

Here's an example:
I have the following in `Column D`

```
Health and environmentNot Applicable
Labour standardsYes
```

In `Column A` I have the categories

```
Health and environment
Labour standards
```

and need `Not Applicable` and `Yes` to go in the corresponding row of `column B`.

I have about 200 categories and 2000 sets that I need to separate as described.

I have been playing around with `vlookup`, `match`, `right`, but cannot get it to work.

I am copying the data from a website and that's the only way it pastes into Excel. 
It is not always lower case followed by upper case; sometimes there is ")" in the end of the category.
I could put the categories in a different sheet.

Comment: Do you have another database where all possible categories are listed?

Comment: 1) Is there always a transition between lower and upper case at the boundary between category and string and 2) why is the data like this? Perhaps you can fix things at the data importation stage

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I responded to the clarification questions in the end of my original post.

Comment: "I am copying the data from a website and that's the only way it pastes into Excel" -- I doubt that. Have you tried the text-to-columns wizard? Also, even if the clipboard does a poor job -- have you looked at the page source? You might be able to parse that. In any event -- you need to decide on a clear criterion to use to split the string. With such a criterion, it is probably a straightforward regular expression problem. Without such a criterion the problem is ill-posed.

Comment: Thank you, John! I was able to get it in a way that the values I want are in the cell underneath the category cell. And I managed to organize it work using the following: =INDEX(A$1:A$250,MATCH(R$1,$A$1:$A$250,0)+1,1).  Now, I have an easier I think question: How do I drag this formula DOWN and have both A$1:A$250 references move a COLUMN to the right?

Answer (score 1):

If you paste in `Column D` that exact string that contains the corresponding category of `Column A`, then this formula in `Column B` gives the exact output you are looking for:

```
=MID(D2,LEN(A2)+1,LEN(D2)-LEN(A2))
```

**EDIT**:

If you need to, use a `replace` function to remove any unwanted characters like "`)(`"

Comment: This would work if the element in column D is always parallel to the corresponding element in column A, which is consistent with but not clear from OP's somewhat vague description and perhaps not too likely because of the reference to `vlookup`. I suspect that if this is all there was to it OP would have figured it out. Still, this is a reasonable answer (+1).

Comment: @JohnColeman yes, question is unclear from OP. But, assuming provided example, I think it answers it.

Comment: I also believe data extracting process should be improved.

Answer (score 0):

In every case, you need to recognize when the category ends and the text begins. As far as I can see, you have two options:

1) Rely that the category always ends with a lowercase letter or a `)`, and that the text always begins with an uppercase letter, and vice versa. If you can rely on that, you can easily split the text from the category.

2) If you have a "database" with all possible category names, you can do a simple pattern match:

For each entry (which is a string), check if and where one of your category names is contained as a sub-string. If you find one, check the remaining string for the next category sub-string.

If you find one, the text between the first and the second category sub-string is normal text which belongs to the first category; store that category and text. If you don't find a next (second) category sub-string, the first category you had found is the only category in that entry, and the rest of the entry (the whole remaining string) is the text which belongs to that category.

Now cut off the leading category and its text from the entry. If the remaining entry is empty, you are done. If not, repeat the process described above with the remaining entry.

But be aware that this will fail if there are texts which accidentally contain category names.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was able to do it!

Comment: Glad to hear that. So why not accept one of the answers given so far?